# Run Delayed Jobs and Sidekiq at the same time

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, sidekiq

I currently use delayed job to process jobs asynchronously. Instead of creating workers, I use the `.delay` method a lot.

I want to move to Sidekiq, but I have too many types of jobs, and can't make sure all of them are thread safe. So I want to run Delayed Job and Sidekiq in parallel, and migrating one type of job at a time.

Since both Delayed Job and Sidekiq offers the `.delay` method, how can I make the distinction between the two? Are there any other potential issues?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For Sidekiq 2.17.1 and later, somewhere in the Rails initializers, call the following:

```
Sidekiq.hook_rails!
Sidekiq.remove_delay!
```

and you will have only prefixed `sidekiq_delay` methods and so on.

([official document](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions#disabling-extensions))

---

For older versions of Sidekiq:

Put the following in `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`

```
module Sidekiq::Extensions::Klass
  alias :sidekiq_delay :delay
  remove_method :delay
  alias :sidekiq_delay_for :delay_for
  remove_method :delay_for
  alias :sidekiq_delay_until :delay_until
  remove_method :delay_until
end

module Sidekiq::Extensions::ActiveRecord
  alias :sidekiq_delay :delay
  remove_method :delay
  alias :sidekiq_delay_for :delay_for
  remove_method :delay_for
  alias :sidekiq_delay_until :delay_until
  remove_method :delay_until
end

module Sidekiq::Extensions::ActionMailer
  alias :sidekiq_delay :delay
  remove_method :delay
  alias :sidekiq_delay_for :delay_for
  remove_method :delay_for
  alias :sidekiq_delay_until :delay_until
  remove_method :delay_until
end
```

And then you can use `sidekiq_delay` to queue in Sidekiq, and call `delay` to queue in Delayed Job.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone searching for this. I did find Sidekiq now has a setting for this out of the box. All you 
need to do is add `Sidekiq.remove_delay!` to `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`

This is described here:
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Sidekiq has [mix-in](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/extensions/class_methods.rb) that adds `.delay` methods to all classes. Not 100% sure how this will behave but it could result in problems if `delay` you are refering to is on the instance level.

My advice would be to add `sidekiq` library per job until you have moved all you jobs to it. Meaning to avoid including both libraries at the same time, again if possible.