# conflict delayed_job / sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, sidekiq

I have an app with both sidekiq and delayed job gems installed. When I trigger handle_asynchronously in active record models it appear to be handled by sidekiq while I would like to trigger delayed_job.

Is there a way to desactivate sidekiq for a specific model?

Comment: note that delayed_job is triggered on non activerecord inherited classes

Comment: what is the `self` getting stored in it (db) does it persist because if not delayed_job on work if the record persist

Comment: apparently it works as it, it saves the object and his state even with relationships

Comment: My friend your a victim of ruby meta-programming I believe check [this](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/extensions/active_record.rb#L24-L26) and [this](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/message_sending.rb#L17-L19) The only resort I believe is that you perhaps use `__delay__` method instead of `delay` because that what `handle_asynchronously` do internally it invoke `delay` method which in your case is invoking the `SideKiq` because thanks to of ghost class or eigen class :)

Comment: As an approach I would suggest is to overwrite [this](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/message_sending.rb#L33-L51) piece of code inside your `lib` or anywhere you like :) , and replace this [line](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/message_sending.rb#L47) with something like this `__delay__(curr_opts).__send__(without_method, *args)` and see if it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in the comment In order to get it working you have to redefine/basically monkey patch the `handle_asynchronously` method something like this

Anywhere you like (but make sure it loaded )

in your **config/initializers/patch.rb** the code look like this

```
module Patch
  def handle_asynchronously(method, opts = {})
    aliased_method, punctuation = method.to_s.sub(/([?!=])$/, ''), $1
    with_method, without_method = "#{aliased_method}_with_delay#{punctuation}", "#{aliased_method}_without_delay#{punctuation}"
    define_method(with_method) do |*args|
      curr_opts = opts.clone
      curr_opts.each_key do |key|
        if (val = curr_opts[key]).is_a?(Proc)
          curr_opts[key] = if val.arity == 1
            val.call(self)
          else
            val.call
          end
        end
      end
      ## Replace this with other syntax
      # delay(curr_opts).__send__(without_method, *args)
      __delay__(curr_opts).__send__(without_method, *args)
    end
    alias_method_chain method, :delay
  end
end

Module.send(:include,Patch)
```

And I believe rest all will  follow then they way it should :)

### Reason:

Delayed::Job include `delay` method on Object and Sidekiq include it `delay` method over ActiveRecord
Hence when the class try to invoke `delay` it look up it ancestors class (including the Eigen Class)
and it find the method define or included in ActiveRecord::Base class (which is sidekiq delay)

why does `__delay__` work because alias define the copy of the existing method which is `delay` method of DelayedJob , hence when you invoke the `__delay__` method it invoke `delay` method define `DelayedJob`
include to `Object`

### Note:

Although the solution is bit patch but the it works . Keeping in mind that every direct  `.delay` methid invocation is invoking `delay` method of the SideKiq and not DelayedJob to invoke the DelayedJob `delay` method you always has call it this way `__delay__`

### Suggestion :

Monkey Patching is just a bad practice on my personal note I would rather not use 2 entirely different background processing library  for a single application to achieve the same task. If the task is process thing in background why cant it be done with a single library either `delayed_job` or `sidekiq` (why it is that you required both of them )

So the point and to simply thing make your background processing an ease with respect to future I sincerely advice you take any one of the two library for background processing and I feel that would the **valid** answer for your question instead of monkey patching an doing other crazy stuff

Hope this help

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:

Sidekiq now provides ways to either disable its `delay` module completely or alias it as `sidekiq_delay`. Please check this to see how to do it. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions#disabling-extensions

---

For older version of sidekiq:

I use [this monkey patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14972111/474597) to make it so that calling `.sidekiq_delay()` goes to sidekiq and `.delay()` is goes to DelayedJob. According the answer by Viren, I think this may also solve your problem.

The patch is less complex (just a bunch of aliases), and gives you the power to consciously decide which `delay` you are actually calling.